# buffered reader input into char array

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io

I want to take an input from a txt file and put all the characters to the array so I can perform on it some regex functions. But when I try to read the array with a single loop to check it, nothing appears. What is wrong here?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task2.doTask2();
        }catch(Exception e){};
    }
}

class Task2
{
    public static void doTask2() throws Exception
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("F:\\Filip\\TextTask2.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        char[] sentence = null;
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        while((i = br.read()) != -1)
        {
            sentence[j] = (char)i;
            j++;
        }
        for(int g = 0; g < sentence.length; g++)
        {
            System.out.print(sentence[g]);
        }

        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you used `i` instead of `g` in the second loop, but if this is the real code you would have got an exception you haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file simply using [`File.readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-). Then it's not necessary to create separate readers.

```
String text = new String(
    Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("F:\\Filip\\TextTask2.txt"))
);
```

In the original snippet, the file reading function is throwing a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) because `sentence` was initialized to `null` and then dereferenced: `sentence[j] = (char)i;`

The exception was swallowed by the calling function and not printed, which is why you're not seeing it when you run the program: `}catch(Exception e){};`

Instead of swallowing the exception declare the calling function as throwing the appropriate checked exception. That way you'll see the stack trace when you run it: `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {`

Comment: I see, I added e.printStackTrace() to see the information, and yeah it shows me NullPointerException.
How it would look like if I want to use BufferedReader anyway?

Comment: And also what I need to import to use your method?

Comment: java.nio.file.Files and java.nio.file.Paths.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong index , use "g" instead of "i" here.:

```
System.out.println(sentence[g]);
```

Also, the best and simplest way to do this is:

```
package io;
import java.nio.file.*;;
public class ReadTextAsString
{
  public static String readFileAsString(String fileName)throws Exception
  {
     return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String data = readFileAsString("F:\\Filip\\TextTask2.txt");
    System.out.println(data); //or iterate through data if you want to print each character.    
  }
}
```

Comment: ohk no problem, if still facing issues then do let me know.
I'm on mobile and don't have access to any IDE to dry run your code, it was just the first mistake i noticed at a glance.

Comment: Why intialize to `""`?